# Leaflet.Draw only edit GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to enable editing of a GeoJSON layer in my Leaflet map using Leaflet Draw. I need to allow only a single edit at a time before saving the results back to the database. I tried to implement the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932125/how-to-allow-only-one-feature-polygon-to-be-edited-at-a-time-with-leaflet). However, each time I activate the draw tool to edit a feature I get the following error in my console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'previousOptions' of undefined
```

These are the key bits of code

My drawnItems layer:

```
drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems)
```

My getJSON:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
            geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data,{
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                }
            });
            map.addLayer(drawnItems);
        });
```

My draw control:

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: false,
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        remove: false,
        edit: true
   }
});

map.addControl(drawControl);


map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            console.log(layer)
        });
    });
```

My GeoJSON is definitely valid (checked with geojson.lint) and have tried to just add a single feature rather than a FeatureCollection.

I have tried to follow some other posts (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/187) but none have solved my problem.